# Не работает PHP + POST

Tags: php

Помогите разобраться почему не работает. При вводе любого значения выкидывает на error.php

```
if(!empty($_POST['paswd'])) {
    $pass = array("soekfpsoioheuf","434","weof[wefw[");   
    $result = in_array($pass);
    if($_POST['paswd']==$result){
        header("Location: page2.php") ;
    }
    else {
       header("Location: error.php") ;
    }
}


<form method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="paswd" placeholder="пароль"><br>
      <input type="submit" class="button alt" value="Войти">
</form>
<br>
```

Comment: Функция `in_array` имеет минимум два параметра и возвращает булево значение. Что с чем вы вообще хотели сравнить?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте так:

```
if (!empty($_POST['paswd']))
{
    $pass = array("soekfpsoioheuf","434","weof[wefw[");

    if (in_array($_POST['paswd'], $pass)) {
        header("Location: page2.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        header("Location: error.php");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: `exit` еще в конец